# Springboot + Axios JWT HTTPonly cookie is null

Tags: spring-boot, axios

I cant get this cookie verification filter to work in springboot. I can also see the cookie in postman but not browser.

I generate the cookie in the following:

```
    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@RequestBody User loginRequest) {
        Authentication authentication =
                authenticationManager.authenticate(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getEmail(), loginRequest.getPassword())); // gets error here

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        MyUserDetails userDetails = (MyUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        ResponseCookie jwtCookie = jwtUtils.generateJwtCookie(userDetails);
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream().map(item -> item.getAuthority()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
                .body(userService.findUserProfileUserByEmail(userDetails.getEmail()));
    }
```

When a request is sent to a restricted access endpoint, it will be run through this filter in the `SecurityConfiguration`

```
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

This is the class:

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String email = jwtUtils.getEmailFromJwtToken(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); // throws error here
                System.out.println("a");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) { return jwtUtils.getJwtFromCookies(request); }
}
```

Here on line `String jwt = parseJwt(request)`, it will always equal null.

I was told this may be an issue with the actual request itself, that it should contain `{withCredentials: true}` in Axios, though doing this raises other issues, and does not explain why this cookie exists and is visible in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this.
By default, spring security only allow GET method from different CORS.
You have to config CORS for different site.
Configure CORS in WebMvcConfigurer not work in Security

[Enable config CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H51FM.png)
[Config CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nuky.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).